# Google Chrome + Youtube (Embedded) + JCarousel = Huge Memory Leaks

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, jcarousel

I'm having some memory issues with having an embedded youtube video in an a image slider (JCarousel), and it's happening on Google Chrome.

How do I fix the memory leak other than removing the video? Thanks...

http://www.leisurepark.com.sg/staging